# Hover property not working for div from different containers

Tags: html, css

I have two different boxes when want to be able to change the properties of one box as I hover somewhere else.

I figured that if I have both boxes in the same container it works as you can see on my [snippet here.](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/qRrXQy)
Here my html and css:

```css
.first {
  color: blue;
  background: black;
  width: 299px;
}
.first:hover + .second {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.second {
  color: red;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam delectus quo corporis, n
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing e et magnam rem, doloribus libero quas numquam esse in culpa!
  </div>
</div>
```

But how can I do the same thing if the boxes are not in the same container?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell us , what you need exactly

Comment: May be hard just with HTML and CSS. Use JavaScript

Comment: With CSS, you can not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `display: inline-block` you can remove the use of the container but because you are using `display: flex` on the container class you won't have the advantage of the child items (the first and second divs) stretching to fill the height of the container. You could use a fixed height to keep them at an equal height.

```css
.first{
  color: blue;
  background: black;
  width: 299px;

  display: inline-block;
}
.first:hover + .second {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.second{
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam delectus quo corporis, n
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing e et magnam rem, doloribus libero quas numquam esse in culpa!
  </div>
```

Comment: This misses the point completely. (while I agree that flexbox sucks)

Answer (score 0):

(post edited)

Use Jquery : Create a new class with a background color, it will be added with Jquery and removed when your mouse left the div.

Code : (don't forget to add jquery)

```
$('div.one').hover(function(){
     $('div.two').toggleClass('three');
});
```

Check this :
https://jsfiddle.net/wnszbhj3/1/

Comment: The boxes are still in the same parent element ("container").

Comment: True, I changed it by a viable answer, thank you for correcting me.